# Get list of files from s3 bucket with a particular substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that has various kinds of file.

Example - `abc.csv, def.tsv, ghi_sub_jkl.avro, mno_sub_pqrs.avro and others.`

I need a function that can give me a list of files that have a particular substring in its filename. 
In the above example I need the files having "sub" as the substring.

Therefore, the output list must contain - `['ghi_sub_jkl.avro', 'mno_sub_pqrs.avro']`

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')

files_list = [file.key for file in my_bucket.objects.all() if 'sub' in file.key]
```